# Dropping host part of the url when loading resources

Tags: javascript, theming, uri

I have a particular problem with the site here. It's a b2b site and it has a word 'advertise' in the domain name. When Drupal loads resources (css/js) it refers to the full url, including that domain name. And those resources are getting blocked by AdBlock on Chrome so as a result site is broken.

Is there a way to refer to css/js locations as local urls (without the host part)?

Comment: Drupal doesn't load resources (css/js), _the browser_ does. Even if you provide a relative path for a CSS file, the browser is going to need to use the full address, including domain name, to download the file. Nothing you can do here except host the files on a different domain

Comment: Sorry, I meant when Drupal outputs headers with urls to resources. How do you setup Drupal to refer to resources on a different domain?

Comment: No my mistake, so are you saying the the ad-block is being invoked because of the URLs in the source of the HTML, not because the browser is physically trying to access those URLs? It's an important distinction to make

Comment: In the header, links to resources look like this: "http://domain.with.advertise.word/themes/some_theme/css/style.css"). AdBlock blocks browser from loading them. I thought the solution may be to set up local links eg: /themes/some_theme/css/style.css. But not sure if this would make difference for AdBlock. But in general trying to find out how to setup the resources links that drupal outputs (either remove host and point locally or enter a different domain)

Comment: Good question, Drupal doesn't have an option for that as far as I've seen...I think you're looking for something like [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63874/how-can-drupal-be-made-to-serve-with-root-relative-paths)

Comment: yes, found theme_process_html function method. However, removing domain/host from the url doesn't sort AdBlock issue. I can use the same function and setup other domain as a resource source but it would then be cross domain for js

Comment: That's what I suspected; Drupal can't help you to solve this unfortunately, it's all about your domain name and ad block's sensitivity to it. Same origin policy shouldn't come into it, though - your css and js won't be loaded in via an xmlhttprequest, so having it on a separate domain is fine security-wise. Not exactly ideal for DNS requests though.

Comment: What's that with not ideal for DNS requests? Why is that? I may be missing something obvious

Comment: Every different domain you have in your code means an extra DNS lookup for the client to perform. Less is better: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#dns_lookups

Comment: Of course. Thanks. I think I need to go for it. Better this than a broken site. And it doesn't seem like client would be willing to change the domain name. BTW, I thought adblock for chrome and firefox are generally the same, but this is an obvious difference in functionality